# QSqlTableModel how to detect that there are pending changes

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

I am using QSqlTableModel/QTableView. editStrategy is OnManualSubmit. I have two buttons Save/Revert. Save's pressed is connected with model's submitAll and Revert's pressed is connected with revertAll. This works perfectly but I want to disable Save And Revert buttons when table doesn't contain any difference with database. So if user changed value of some cell from 5 to 6 my buttons become enabled and if then he changed from 6 to 5 my buttons must again become disabled. Is there a better way for doing this except manually caching model data and comparing with models content on each change?

Comment: What if you watch `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged()` signal of your model to know whether the data is changed or not?

Comment: Have you tried [isDirty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#isDirty-1)? Or is it not smart enough to detect manually reverted changes?

Comment: I do not *think* `QSqlTableModel` retains the "original" values as you change (unlike .NET's `DataRow` which does precisely that).  In which case, yes, you will have to implement your own "original value caching model".